# running multiple cells in jupyter notebook simultaneously

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook). I have a cell in a jupyter notebook that runs for a long time. I want to run the next cell (variables not dependent on the previous cell) along with the previous one. I am not asking for multiprocessing or sharing jobs across CPUs. I want to run the contents of multiple cells run simultaneously. By default, they run sequentially.

It is like running two different notebooks but for the sake of continuity and shared objects, variables I want to run in multiple cells in the same notebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run multiple cells simultaneously in IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Did you find a way to run two notesbooks in the same Colab VM? I try to run bert-as-service (https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service) and need to do xactly that but there doesnt seem to be a way.

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052886/running-a-process-in-the-background-in-jupyter/59600399#59600399

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question has been answered in another post. ipyparallel (formerly IPython parallel) can be used to spawn multiple IPython kernel. [Documentation](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Is there a way to run multiple cells simultaneously in IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook)