# Jupyter notebook, how to run multiple cells simultaneously?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I defined a python function which run a bash script. Let's say the function is: `calc(x,y,z)`. If I run this function in python with some variables,

```
>>> calc(1,2,3)
```

It generates a C code which simulate something using the variables `(x=1, y=2, z=3)`, compiles the C code and executes the compiled output file.

I want to run multiple `calc(x,y,z)`s with different `(x,y,z)`s in jupyter notebook simultaneously. As you may noticed, the problem is that cells in jupyter notebook are executed sequentially. If I run three `calc` functions, it takes three times longer than the one function running time.

I tried two ways but they didn't work well.

1. Use `multiprocessing` module: By using the module, it is possible to execute multiple `calc`s simultaneously in "one cell". But for later analysis, I would like to execute multiple cells simultaneously which include only one `calc` each using different processors (or cpu cores).
2. Use `ipyparallel` cell magic (inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook)): I tried as following after import `ipyparallel`

   ```
   # Cell 1
   %%px --targets 0 # use processor 0
   calc(1,1,1)
   ```

   .

   ```
   # Cell 2
   %%px --targets 1 # use processor 1
   calc(2,2,2)
   ```

   .

   ```
   # Cell 3
   %%px --targets 2 # use processor 2
   calc(3,3,3)
   ```

But the cells are executed sequentially: Cell 2 is executed after Cell 1 simulation was done, similar for Cell 3.

How to run multiple jupyter cells using different cores?

Answer (score 2):

In your solution, the cells are executed by different engines as you expected. The issue is caused by default blocking behavior. You can simply add `--noblock` argument to execute a cell in non-blocking mode. Then the cell returns `AsyncResult` object that makes it possible to read the output once the execution is finished by calling method `display_outputs()`. Go to the documentation for details [targets-and-blocking](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/magics.html#targets-and-blocking)

```
# Cell 1
%%px --targets 0 --noblock
calc(1,1,1)
```

.

```
# Cell 2
%%px --targets 1 --noblock
calc(2,2,2)
```

.

```
# Cell 3
%%px --targets 2 --noblock
calc(3,3,3)
```

If you need to access the output you can call `display_outputs()` as I explained above.

```
# output of the first the cell 1
___.display_outputs()

# output of the first the cell 2
__.display_outputs()

# output of the first the cell 1
_.display_outputs()
```

I used underscore notation to access `AsyncResult` objects returned by the cells 1-3. There is a number of other ways to access those objects, for example by using `Out[x]` where x is the cell's execution number visible in the notebook after executing a cell.