# Background thread clock in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In my Jupyter notebook, I want to execute some long running background jobs and display their status in a cell. I thought, before doing something difficult, I could start with a clock.

I have the following code in one cell

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import display
import threading

out = widgets.Output()

@out.capture(clear_output=True, wait=True)
def display_time():
    now = dt.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    display(HTML(f"""<h1><center>{now}</center></h1>"""))

def run_time():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        display_time()

out
```

When I call `run_time()` I get the time nicely updated every second, but my notebook is blocking on this cell. So I tried `threading.Thread(target=run_time).start()` but this somehow only updates the time whenever I do interactions with the notebook. How can I update the notebook even if I do not do any cell interactions?

Comment: Did you manage to do what you wanted ? If so, what did you use ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at `ipyrallel` to run multi kernels in you notebook.

Here is a [solved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook)

Here is the [documentation](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, `ipyrallel` can be used for multithreading in general - and also for clusters. All I want to do is to start a separate thread that displays data in a notebook. I hoped that there was something simpler.

Comment: Yes so it allows you to choose which core from your laptop will be used to run a cell. Therefore you can run 1 cell with 1 core for the TimeClock and run the rest of your notebook on another one. It is a bit tricky but it should work