# Simultaneously running jupyter notebook cells?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run 2 jupyter notebook cells simultaneously.

First, I define

```
import time
list1 = ["a"]
```

Then i want to run the following

```
go = True
while go==True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(list1)
```

While the cell above is running, i want to be able to update list1 and see the updated output in the cell above i.e. run another cell

```
list1.append("b")
```

I have looked into using ipyparallel package and tried to use this answer and documentation with no success
[Is there a way to run multiple cells simultaneously in IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `multiprocess` module in order to run parallel cells

You probably need to use multiprocess `Manager`'s list and `Value` in order to get shared variables between threads

```
import time
from multiprocess import Manager, Process, Value

manager = Manager()
list1 = manager.list(["a"])
go = Value('b', True)

def worker(list1, go):
    while go.value:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(list1)
    return

p = Process(target=worker, args=(list1, go))
p.start()
```

To update `list1` in another cell, you can try something like mentioned above

```
list1.append("b")
```

To update `go`, you can set its `value` property to be the value you want

```
go.value = True # This will output list1 in worker
go.value = False # This exit worker while loop
```