# How tensorboard can plot more evaluation than the last step?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, metrics, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I am trying to plot a continuous graph for the evaluation of my model.
Tensorboard (v2.4.1) succeed to plot the different losses for each step.
Nevertheless it only plots the last step for the evaluation and I only have a dot on my evaluation curves.

Here is my tensorboard view :
[Tensorboard show only the last step's evaluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H73pF.png)

I run tensorboard with this command : `tensorboard --logdir=models/my_model`
I run my evaluation with this command : `python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_model --pipeline_config_path=models/my_model/pipeline.config --checkpoint_dir=models/my_model --run_once=True`

Here is my pipeline config file :

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 768
        max_dimension: 768
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_efficientnet-b2_bifpn_keras"
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: SWISH
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.9900000095367432
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
        force_use_bias: true
      }
      bifpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        num_iterations: 5
        num_filters: 112
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 1.0
        x_scale: 1.0
        height_scale: 1.0
        width_scale: 1.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: SWISH
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.9900000095367432
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
          force_use_bias: true
        }
        depth: 112
        num_layers_before_predictor: 3
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 3
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 1.5
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    add_background_class: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 16
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
      output_size: 768
      scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
      scale_max: 2.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.07999999821186066
          total_steps: 100000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.0010000000474974513
          warmup_steps: 2500
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models/efficientdet_d2_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 200000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_img_train.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  num_visualizations: 30
  save_graph: true
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_img_test.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
}
```

Do you have an idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

#### As of 02.2022

##### TL;DR:

The Tensorboard plotted only one dot for Validation because the Validation process only took into account *the* latest Checkpoint. **After** Training was done, the Checkpoints were fed into Validation process, which considered only the last Checkpoint.

##### Long Answer:

The Validation process is supposed to run simultaneously at the same time with Training process (see the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f670e89c47573d1f0465bd1a20b4c36dae064be1/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py#L82) below). This is typically not possible with Notebook-like environment, e.g. CoLab, because the script is executed step-by-step (one cell at a time; in each cell, one command at a time).

```
def eval_continuously(
    pipeline_config_path,
    config_override=None,
    train_steps=None,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=1,
    use_tpu=False,
    override_eval_num_epochs=True,
    postprocess_on_cpu=False,
    model_dir=None,
    checkpoint_dir=None,
    wait_interval=180,
    timeout=3600,
    eval_index=0,
    save_final_config=False,
    **kwargs):
  """Run continuous evaluation of a detection model eagerly.
  This method builds the model, and continously restores it from the most
  recent training checkpoint in the checkpoint directory & evaluates it
  on the evaluation data.
```

Nevertheless, there may be [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248345/is-there-a-way-to-run-multiple-cells-simultaneously-in-ipython-notebook) to workaround (get them running simultaneously). However, in my opinion, this might be less optimal as both Training and Validation would compete for system resources, especially GPU, which could lead to slower Training time.

An ideal solution is to run the Training in one machine, get it saving the Checkpoint into a shared Disk (e.g. Google Drive), and have another machine run the Validation, in which the aforementioned Checkpoints are fetched. Both the machines should run at the same time.

However, there is still a challenge: in function `eval_continuously()`, [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f670e89c47573d1f0465bd1a20b4c36dae064be1/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py#L1136):

```
for latest_checkpoint in tf.train.checkpoints_iterator( # Here!
      checkpoint_dir, timeout=timeout, min_interval_secs=wait_interval):
    ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
        step=global_step, model=detection_model, optimizer=optimizer)
```

`checkpoints_iterator()` is used, and its description is as followed:

```
def checkpoints_iterator(checkpoint_dir,
                         min_interval_secs=0,
                         timeout=None,
                         timeout_fn=None):
  """Continuously yield new checkpoint files as they appear.
  The iterator only checks for new checkpoints when control flow has been
  reverted to it. This means it can miss checkpoints if your code takes longer
  to run between iterations than `min_interval_secs` or the interval at which
  new checkpoints are written.
```

That said, the function may miss some Checkpoints. A corner case that I can imagine: The Validation process takes too long (e.g. due to big Dataset). At the moment, more new Checkpoint files are written. When the function begins checking for Checkpoint agains, it **only considers the latest Checkpoint**, meaning the Validation will miss the Checkpoints before the latest one! (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3f878cff5b698b82eea85db2b60d65a2e320850e/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py#L139) for the proof). Therefore, the data for plotting Validation would be less fine-grained.