# How can I evaluate multiple checkpoints with the TF2 Object Detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I've successfully trained a model with around 16k steps which produced quite a few checkpoints that are saved in my `training` folder. I want to make sure that I am not running into overfitting issues, so I would like to evaluate every single checkpoint with my testing data.

I am using the following command from the official [Tensorflow 2 Object Detection repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md):

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH={path to pipeline config file}
MODEL_DIR={path to model directory}
CHECKPOINT_DIR=${MODEL_DIR}
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --checkpoint_dir=${CHECKPOINT_DIR} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

`MODEL_DIR` and `CHECKPOINT_DIR` are both pointing to my `training` folder.

The issue I am experiencing now is that this only evaluates the latest checkpoint, but I'd like to  evaluate all of them at once.

Ideally I would like to see the results in TensorBoard which shows the val_accuracy (mAP) of the different checkpoints as graph - which it does already, but just for the one checkpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### As of 02.2022

The Validation process is supposed to run at the same time with the Training process so that whenever a new Checkpoint is saved, the Validation process immediately loads the Checkpoint and starts validating.

Please see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129513/1860314) in this regard.